# get info from Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I have the following example, I would like if you enter the AGE in the Html field, then it shows the people who are older than what was entered.So all info is in the object

```js
function zeig() {
  const Studen = [{
      name: "Ahmad",
      Alter: "35",
      Schule: "Abitur"
    },
    {
      name: "Salim",
      Alter: "88",
      Schule: "Secandschule"
    },
    {
      name: "Esraa",
      Alter: "22",
      Schule: "Abitur"
    },
  ]

  /* let ergebniss=Studen.map(function(sami){
  return ` Name der Stundent  ${sami.name}  Alter ${sami.Alter} `+"<br>"
   */
  let ergebniss = Studen

    .filter(function(sami) {
      return sami.Alter > document.getElementById("nameinput").nodeValue;

    })
    .map(function(sami) {
      return `Name der Student <div class="meinname"> ${sami.name} </div> Alter der Student ${sami.Alter}` + "<br>";


    });



  document.querySelector("#show").innerHTML += ergebniss;
}
```

```css
.meinname {
  color: rgb(57, 0, 214);
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">

  <div class="formullar" style="align-items: center; text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Bitte hier eintragen</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nameinput">
    <input type="text" id="alterinput">
    <input type="button" id="send" value="zeigen" onclick="zeig()">

  </div>
</form>
<div id="show" style="align-items: center; text-align: center;"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Moved the <form> to where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work better

Use eventListener

```js
const Studenten = [{
    name: "Ahmad",
    Alter: "35",
    Schule: "Abitur"
  },
  {
    name: "Salim",
    Alter: "88",
    Schule: "Sekundarschule"
  },
  {
    name: "Esraa",
    Alter: "22",
    Schule: "Abitur"
  },
]

document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
  const Alter = document.getElementById("nameinput").value
  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = Studenten
    .filter(sami => sami.Alter > Alter)
    .map(sami => `Name der Student <div class="meinname"> ${sami.name} </div> Alter der Student ${sami.Alter}`).join('<br/>')
});
```

```css
.meinname {
  color: rgb(57, 0, 214);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <div class="formullar" style="align-items: center; text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Bitte hier eintragen</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nameinput">
    <input type="text" id="alterinput">
    <input type="submit" value="zeigen">

  </div>
</form>
<div id="show" style="align-items: center; text-align: center;"></div>
```